# How to use c++ array at run time and change the values it holds?

Tags: c++, arrays

Very novice question here.

So I have this int array and using sfml I've used this int array to map textures to  the screen in a grid like structure.  I was wondering how you would go about knowing what square you're mouse is above in the array at run time.

```
int mapArr[] = { 
0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0
}
```

^something like so.

So using something like below will change the top left most square to a different texture.

```
mapArr[0] = { 1 };

int mapArr[] = { 
1, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0
}
```

So how would I implement this based on if my mouse was above the top left square and want to do something like mapArr[0] = { 1 };  at runtime?

https://gist.github.com/jbax86/94ee0b326a30f4dd80efbb33791f6728

Comment: `mapArr[0] = 1;` ??

Comment: Are you actually asking how to assign a value to an element of an array or are you asking how to check whether the mouse is located over a given rectangle? Those are two very different questions… ;-)

Comment: `sf::Mouse::getPosition();`, you can optionally pass in a `sf::Window` to the function to get the position relative to the window instead of relative to your desktop. Alternatively you can poll for `sf::Event::MouseMoved` and get the coordinates from the event.

Comment: This is all well covered in the [tutorials on their site](https://en.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/) for more details.

Comment: Intuition tells me [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/212808/treating-a-1d-data-structure-as-2d-grid) will help you near in the future

Comment: @alseether thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// 25x15 array for 800x600 display are my settings.
int mapArr[];    

int MouseToMap(int x, int y, int val)
{
    mapArr[25 * y + x] = val;
};

// at a calling location inside main somewhere.  
// for sfml I put it in the event listening part of loop.
// 25 is tiles across not 0 indexed,
// 32 is tile width of tile in pixels.

sf::vector2i mVal = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
MouseToMap(mVal.x / 32, mVal.y / 32, 3);
```

Comment: `mapArr[4 * x + y]` should probably be `mapArr[4 * y + x]`?